# mocking an error/exception in rspec (not just its type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a block of code like this:

```
def some_method
  begin
    do_some_stuff
  rescue WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
    if e.response_code.to_i == 503
      handle_the_situation
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test what's going on in that `if e.response_code.to_i == 503` section.  I can mock do_some_stuff to throw the right type of exception:

```
whatever.should_receive(:do_some_stuff).and_raise(WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
```

but how do I mock the error object itself to return 503 when it receives "response_code"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
require 'mechanize'

class Foo

  def some_method
    begin
      do_some_stuff
    rescue WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
      if e.response_code.to_i == 503
        handle_the_situation
      end
    end
  end

end

describe "Foo" do

  it "should handle a 503 response" do
    page = stub(:code=>503)
    foo = Foo.new
    foo.should_receive(:do_some_stuff).with(no_args)\
    .and_raise(WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError.new(page))
    foo.should_receive(:handle_the_situation).with(no_args)
    foo.some_method
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays RSpec ships with [verifying doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles) which make sure that your mock object conforms to the real object's API (i.e. its available methods/method calls).

```rb
require 'mechanize'

class Foo

  def some_method
    begin
      do_some_stuff
    rescue WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
      if e.response_code.to_i == 503
        handle_the_situation
      end
    end
  end

end

RSpec.describe Foo do
  subject(:foo) { described_class.new }
  
  describe "#some_method" do
    subject { foo.some_method }

    let(:mechanize_error) { instance_double(WWW::Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, response_code: '503') }

    before { expect(foo).to receive(:do_some_stuff).and_raise(mechanize_error) }
  
    it "handles a 503 response" do
      expect(foo).to receive(:handle_the_situation)  # Assert error handler will be called
      subject
    end
  end
end
```

I try to write tests as clearly and cleanly as possible since code is read once by a computer, but hundreds of times by humans (your coworkers/team members)!