# Mocking request timeout in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a class that makes a request to another service and I want to test error handing around that request.

The code looks like this:

```
  response = RequestObject.post #this triggers a HTTP request

  LocalObject.update(foreign_id: response.id, retrieved_at: Time.current )
```

In my tests I stub the request out and return JSON on success, but I want to test that if that response raises an error that the `:foreign_id` and `:retrieved_at` aren't set.

I stub the successful request like this:

```
allow(RequestObject).to receive(:post).and_return({id: 1,})
```

What's a good way to mock `RequestObject` raising a timeout error?

(I'm using the [Faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) for my requests)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067801/mocking-an-error-exception-in-rspec-not-just-its-type?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#and_raise` to mock an error.

```
allow(RequestObject).to receive(:post).and_raise(SomeError)
```

That should allow you to test that code path.

[Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error)'s a link to the rspec docs.